# Why is there a gap at the side of my graph? (matplotlib/py)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Got a list of 5 elements which represents sequences of objects. i.e. element 0 represents the number 1, and so on. Consequently I had to do this to have these numbers represented properly on the graph:

```
higher_chances.insert(0, 0)
plt.xlim(1,len(higher_chances))
plt.xticks(range(1, len(higher_chances)))
```

So basically, I inserted a 0 at start of list, then ignored it. Let me know if there's a better way to do this

Consequently I now have a gap on the right-hand side of my graph and can't figure out how to remove it. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

List: [0, 47.0, 46.0, 45.0, 45.0, 43.0]

All code below:

```
# Inset 0 at first index so index 1 reflect sequence of 1 candle
higher_chances.insert(0, 0)

# Convert to actual percentages for presentation
higher_chances = [ elem*100 for elem in higher_chances]

plt.plot(higher_chances)
plt.ylim(min(higher_chances[1:]), max(higher_chances[1:]))
plt.xlim(1,len(higher_chances))
plt.xticks(range(1, len(higher_chances)))

plt.xlabel('Number of consecutive bull candles', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('% chance of another bull candle following', fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

## Edit:

If I add `plt.axis('tight')` without changing other code the graph changes to:

[image]

If I take out `xlim/ylim` and add `plt.axis('tight')` the graph does not change from that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
plt.xlim(1,len(higher_chances))
```

To:

```
plt.xlim(1,len(higher_chances)-1)
```

[image]

But leave the following as it is, if I add -1 as per above it removes the last label:

```
plt.xticks(range(1, len(higher_chances)))
```

[image]